# One computer on my network won't connect to the network without a reboot

Tags: windows-xp, networking, network-adapter

My computer is on a local network that contains about 300 PCs. NIC is not built-in (i.e. the built-in NIC doesn't work). I don't know whether my IP is assigned staticly or by DHCP.

Every time my system starts, it doesn't connect to the network until it's rebooted. This problem affects just the one computer.

Comment: Static or DHCP? Have you tried a second NIC? Define "network doesn't work". Do you still get an IP? when it isn't working, what is your ipconfig readout like? Do you have other computers on the network? do they ever experience similar issues?

Comment: @MaQleod Thanx, please read my edited question.

Comment: so let me get this strait: 1. you turn it on 2. network doesnt work 3. you reboot 4. network then works? Is it a cold boot initially or is the computer waking up from hibernation/sleep. Your computer could be asleep longer then your DHCP lease lasts so it will need a new address when waking up...

Comment: @Kyle Thanx, so it is just initially boot (at the morning).

Comment: What do you mean by the network isn't allowed? do you get a specific error message? It still would be helpful to see the IPconfig readout from when it doesn't get an IP

Comment: @MaQleod Thanx, I don't know how this message translates to Englsish, but it's default message (maybe _unreachable_). So If I see that ipconfig doesn't get an IP what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried simply cycling the connection off/on, vs restarting the box?  (Sounds like maybe the first DHCP handshake was fumbled.  Can other boxes "see" your box at all?)